# Node - nodemailer send mail in case of success

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have the below code to save a new entry in my database Mongo, I would like to send an email with nodemailer just in case of success "res.status(201)".
Where my code should be place ?

```
    register: (req, res, next) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        .then(hash => {
            const person= new Person({
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hash
            });
            person.save()
                .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: "OK" }))
                .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ message: error }))
        })
        .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ message: error }));
},
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

```
register: (req, res, next) => {
bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then(hash => {
        const person= new Person({
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hash
        });
        person.save()
            .then(() =>
               {
               res.status(201).json({ message: "OK" }))
               ... nodemailer here ...
               }
            .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({ message: error }))
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).json({ message: error }));
```

},